# MySQL Query with Distinct on Two Different Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I'm trying to build a query that will give me results that are distinct in two separate columns, `user_name` and `year_taken`.

If I have results of my current query that look like this. These are basically all of the tests taken.

| user_name | test_taken | score | year_taken |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob Smith | 101 | 85 | 2020 |
| Jan Jones | 101 | 99 | 2020 |
| Mike Jackson | 101 | 54 | 2021 |
| Bob Smith | 201 | 74 | 2020 |
| Mike Jackson | 201 | 70 | 2020 |
| Jan Jones | 300 | 75 | 2020 |
| Mike Jackson | 300 | 55 | 2021 |
| Bob Smith | 301 | 95 | 2021 |
| Mike Jackson | 301 | 97 | 2022 |

I need to narrow it down to just one test per year, per user. So, the results I'd like to get look like this:

| user_name | test_taken | score | year_taken |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob Smith | 101 | 85 | 2020 |
| Jan Jones | 101 | 99 | 2020 |
| Mike Jackson | 101 | 54 | 2021 |
| Mike Jackson | 201 | 70 | 2020 |
| Bob Smith | 301 | 95 | 2021 |
| Mike Jackson | 301 | 97 | 2022 |

So, I need one test per one user per year.

My query draws from a few different tables, but it boils down to

```
select user_name, test_taken, score, year_taken from ....
```

I'm just not sure how to base a distinct on another column as well.

Comment: You say _"I need to narrow it down to just one test per year"_ but you don't specify what criteria have to be used to achieve that.

Comment: I'm sorry. I need one test per user per year. So, just if Bob Smith took three tests in 2020, I just need one result for him. If Jan Jones only took one test in 2020, still one result. If Bob Smith took multiple tests in 2020, 2021 and 2022 each, then just three results for him, one for each year. That's the only criteria. Does that make more sense?

Comment: What about the score? Do you pick always highest?

Comment: Again, I apologize, I wasn't clear. The test and score do not matter. All that matters is the user and the year. I just need one result per user per year.

Comment: If you don't mind the value of the score field, why you're carrying it with you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`, as in:

```
select *
from (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by user_name, year_taken 
                              order by score desc) as rn
  from t
) x
where rn = 1
```